# Qual melhora mais o desempenho: usar "async" ou colocar <script> no final da página?

Tags: javascript

Costuma-se citar como boas práticas para o desempenho:

- Colocar tags `<script></script>` no final da página, antes do `</body>`
- Usar async: `<script async="async" src="..." ></script>`

Qual das duas dá o melhor resultado em termos de desempenho?

Comment: Acho que isso é como comparar maçãs com laranjas. Ambas as formas que você menciona têm propósitos diferentes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambas as alternativas não vão interromper o render da página, logo, do ponto de vista do usuário, tem o mesmo resultado.

Se você pretende dar suporte a browsers mais antigos, coloque os scripts no final.

`async` executa o script assim que ele for baixado, sem interromper o render. Utilize-o para scripts que independem da ordem de execução (normalmente js puro). Note que você não tem suporte para esse recurso no IE8.

Colocar o script no final vai permitir renderizar toda a página e só então carregar o script.

Estude o conteúdo de sua página e verifique se há scripts que devem estar disponíveis assim que a página estiver carregada.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar a resposta

Tanto `async` e `defer` são bons para browsers modernos, alias, browsers modernos já estão fazendo carregamento de .js em paralelo automaticamente. Ambos só tem suporte no IE 10+,Opera nem sonha em ter, Chrome 20+ (confirmar)

Colocar arquivos JavaScript no `<head>` ou espalhado no meio do HTML é má prática há anos. A boa prática é sempre jogar para antes do `</body>`.

Para o carregamento assincrono, recomendo a utilização de bibliotecas com objetivo de carregar JavaScript em paralelo assincronamente, como LABjs, HeadJS e ControlJS, do próprio Steve Souders papa da otimização web.

http://labjs.com/

utilizando o Labsjs
será algo do tipo:

```
<script>
   $LAB
   .script("framework.js").wait()
   .script("plugin.framework.js")
   .script("myplugin.framework.js").wait()
   .script("init.js").wait();
</script>
```

Para completar a resposta:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

http://labjs.com/documentation.php

Comment: http://zenorocha.com/html5-async-scripts/ esta com link quebrado!!!